# DCMTK: min-max-window vs min-max-window-n vs histogram-window

Tags: image-processing, rendering, dcmtk

I'd like to convert a set of DICOM instances (CT, MR, X-Ray basically) to JPEG (regular 8bits lossy grayscale). I have been starring at the options from [dcmj2pnm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334699/difference-between-dcm2pnm-dcmj2pnm-and-dcml2pnm):

- [dcmj2pnm: Convert DICOM images to PGM/PPM, PNG, TIFF, JPEG or BMP](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmj2pnm.html)

I am quite confident that `--use-window 1` is the right option when the input DICOM instance provide a single value for (0028,1050) Window Center & (0028,1051) Window Width. What I fail to understand is what is the "right" option to choose from (when WC/WW is missing):

1. `--min-max-window`,
2. `--min-max-window-n` (what does `extreme values` mean ?),
3. `--histogram-window 5` (found ref [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.protocols.dicom/c/dxoBHnsbApo/m/_Epylx8_kdcJ))

Are there any good rule of thumb when processing DICOM CT (Pixel Padding Value) images ? MR images ? X-Ray images ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being the author of this DCMTK tool, I should be able to answer your questions.

> I am quite confident that --use-window 1 is the right option when the input DICOM instance provide a single value for (0028,1050) Window Center & (0028,1051) Window Width.

This is at least true if the stored VOI window is correct (i.e. appropriate for the stored pixel data).

> What I fail to understand is what is the "right" option to choose from (when WC/WW is missing):

As a rule of thumb, `--min-max-window` (compute VOI window using min-max algorithm) usually creates good results. If there are extreme values in the image (very low and/or very high pixel values) that do not belong to the medical content, they can be ignored: option `--min-max-window-n` ignores the minimum and maximum values (and use the next lower/higher value in the pixel data as the borders of the VOI window), option `--histogram-window [n]` computes a histogram on the pixel values used in the image and ignores "n" percent of both the low and the high values (when computing the VOI window).

Comment: It would be nice to clarify behavior with regards to `Pixel Padding Value`

Comment: Pixel Padding Value is not taken into account. See DCMTK issue #141: https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/issues/141